# Python Selenium click function doesn't work if there's a time.sleep() after

Tags: python, selenium

**My code, So here for example, the col.click() will only happen after the sleep time, it does the same if I try to find_elements**

My goal here is to click the row of my table, that will load a new webpage and then get an element from there
Any suggestions would be appreciated

**My code,**

```
import time
import pyautogui
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://example.com")
driver.maximize_window()
pyautogui.press('tab')
pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "v")
pyautogui.press('tab')
pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "v")
#pyautogui.write('yes')
pyautogui.press('enter')
driver.find_element_by_link_text("all_links").click()

table_id = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_ContentPage_Supergrid1_dgSupergrid")
rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr") # get all of the rows in the table
for row in rows:
    # Get the columns       
    col = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[0]
    col.click()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: But if you load a new webpage, then you can't access the old one? Is it possible to scrape all the links from the table, loop over those links using driver.get() ?

Comment: I tried scraping the links but it's only a part of the full url needed ex:detail/context.aspx
so I tried adding it to my full url like so x = str(f"mysite.com/{y}")
y as the link variable and it wouldn't work when I pass it to driver.get

Comment: If they lead to another domain, then they should be full, if they lead to the same (which is probably the case), they likely contain only url path. You can do string concatenation to get the full url. If I am missing something, please, add an example.

Comment: I get the links using .getattribute("onclick") and they are only the last part of the url, the only thing I can get with that method is this:

x :  document.location.href='details.aspx?id=247&wfid=28'
y :  details.aspx?id=247&wfid=28

Comment: with the y variable I tried to add it to my string and it worked fine with print() but as soon as I tried driver.get() it didn't work

Comment: When you click the row, it only marks somehow or driver is opening that link? If it is the later one, your second loop does not work, because you are no longer in the same url. You need to go back, find all the rows again, and click the second and so on.

Comment: The click opens the link only if I do not write code like time.sleep(2) or driver.find_element
afterwards, so that's the biggest problem, but now I managed to make it working without the click by using driver.get(). The reason it didn't work is because I had to skip the first row
Thanks for you help btw!

Comment: Still weird how the click opens the link but when I had the time.sleep or find_element(element for the new page), it doesnt open the link anymore

Comment: find_elements will return an array of webelement references.  Once you use a .click() that navigates or triggers a DOM update, those row references you are iterating through will be stale.  If there is no sleep, (or webdriverwait) it may be clicking again before the page updates.  So the reference is not stale because navigation is interrupted.  On the last iteration you may or may not have a click that navigates.  (depending on what follows)